# Why do i get different result between application and playground?

Tags: swift

I get different result from these code in Xcode with swift version 2.2.In playground the result is `false`, but `true` in application.

`let a: Int? = 0
 print(a is Equatable)`

Can anyone give me a reason?
Thanks!

Comment: Should print `true` unless it's `nil`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, prints `true` in playground!

Comment: Same here, but actually I would expect to get `false`, because `Optional<Wrapped>` does *not* conform to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 0):

It will Printed True at Both Playground and Application
Snaps:-

1.At Playground
[image: At Playground]

2.At Application

[image: At Application]

Comment: I'm so sorry that i got the wrong step to do this. Your are right. But optional not implementation the protocol of Equatable. Why we can get the result of the 'true'?

Comment: Apple says that every variable is eauatable. Here we defining the value of a so it will gives true. It's equatable. Means you can compare it.

Comment: But i can get the result of the `false` when the variable type is `Array`. What happened?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172
you can get brief detail about Why you get false from here.